# Junk files generated after compiling C program

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, and using vscode and Code Runner plugin to run a C program. Code runner is configured as follows:

```
"code-runner.executorMap":  {
"c":  "cd $dir && gcc -o $fileNameWithoutExt $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
},
```

The problem is that every time I run any C program, junk files are created as you can see in the following image:

[image]

I would like to know what is happening here.

Comment: they are not from `gcc`, what does your program do

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks. It happens with more than one program. You can find an example [here](https://gist.github.com/lbarqueira/1be0935d4d9f5d85b1457236f4d94bff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, yesterday vscode C++ intellisense debuging update (updated automatically to a pre-release 1.9.5), it is doing the same. All junk files are 0bytes in length and are at the workspace root.
vscode V1.63.2.
ubuntu 20.04lts (up to date)
Actual workspace : platformIO Core 5.2.5 / Home 3.4.1 on STM32 arduino firmware.
As i program for a micro-controler without any file system, i can conclude for sure that it is not user's code dependent. So only the vscode or platform IO environment could generate such junk files.

Others remark, i have been coded for a week now without compiling, so i am pretty sure (but not certain) that the platformio stm gcc is not part of the problem.

Regards

Regards.